# Powershell, XAML, WPF - ListView groupings not working

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml

I need help trying to understand why the list items aren't being grouped in the below example.

The 'Property' and 'Value' data are populating but there is no grouping at all. I have cobbled together this script from online examples without really having a good understanding of XAML and how data binding works etc. and how it should work in a PowerShell context. It *was* working but I refactored the code and the grouping functionality broke and now I can't for the life of me figure out exactly why.

If any one could assist me it would be greatly appreciated.

#### ModalWindow.xaml

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        Title="Confirm User Details" Height="580" Width="360" >

    <Grid Margin="10">
        <ListView Name="DataListView" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="475">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="110" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Property}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="196" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>

            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Margin="5" TextDecorations="Underline" FontSize="13" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
        </ListView>
        <Button Name="ConfirmButton" Content="OK" Height="39" Width="160" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  />
        <Button Name="CancelButton" Content="Cancel" Margin="0" Width="160" Height="39" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    </Grid>

   </Window>
```

#### Main.ps1

```
Function GetListViewItemsSource() {

   Param ($NewADUserParams)

   $Data = @()

   $Groupings = @{
       DEFAULT      = "Other";
       GENERAL      = "General";
       ACCOUNT      = "Account";
       ORGANIZATION = "Organization";
   }

   $IgnoredKeys = @("PassThru", "Enabled")

   $GroupingsMap = @{
       Description           = $Groupings.GENERAL;
       UserPrincipalName     = $Groupings.ACCOUNT;
       DisplayName           = $Groupings.GENERAL;
       SamAccountName        = $Groupings.ACCOUNT;
       AccountExpirationDate = $Groupings.ACCOUNT;
       Name                  = $Groupings.GENERAL;
       Company               = $Groupings.ORGANIZATION;
   }

   ForEach ($Key in $NewADUserParams.Keys) {

       If ($IgnoredKeys -contains $Key) { Continue; }

       $Grouping = $Groupings.DEFAULT

       If ($GroupingsMap.ContainsKey($Key)) {
           $Grouping = $GroupingsMap[$Key]
       }

       $Data += New-Object PSObject -prop @{Property = $Key; Value = $NewADUserParams[$Key]; Grouping = $Grouping; }

   }

   $ListViewItemsSource = [System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView] $Data
   $ListViewItemsSource.GroupDescriptions.Add((New-Object System.Windows.Data.PropertyGroupDescription "Grouping"))


   Return $ListViewItemsSource
}


Function ShowModalWindow() {

   Param ($ListViewItemsSource)

   [XML] $ModalWindowXAML = Get-Content -Path $Config.XAML.ModalWindow

   $NodeReader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $ModalWindowXAML)
   $ModalWindow = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $NodeReader )

   $ListView = $ModalWindow.FindName("DataListView")
   $ListView.ItemsSource = $ListViewItemsSource

   $ConfirmButton = $ModalWindow.FindName("ConfirmButton")
   $CancelButton = $ModalWindow.FindName("CancelButton")

   $Response = @{
       Value = 0
   }

   $ConfirmButton.Add_Click( {
        $Response.Value = 1
        $ModalWindow.Close()
    })

   $CancelButton.Add_Click( {
        $ModalWindow.Close()
    })

   $ModalWindow.ShowDialog()

   Return $Response

}

$NewADUserParams = @{
   # ...
   Description = "bar, foo";
   DisplayName = "bar, foo";
   SamAccountName = "foo.bar";
   AccountExpirationDate = "12/31/9999 00:00:00";
   Name = "foo.bar";
   GivenName = "foo";
   Title = boss;
   OtherAttributes = System.Collections.Hashtable;
   Surname = "bar";
   ChangePasswordAtLogon = True;
   # etc...
}
$ListViewItemsSource = GetListViewItemsSource -NewADUserParams $NewADUserParams
$ConfirmUserProps = ShowModalWindow -ListViewItemsSource $ListViewItemsSource
```

#### Resulting Modal Dialog

[image: Output]

Edit

To clarify, this is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

See: https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/

Comment: The `ItemsSource` collection is not supposed to be grouped. It should be "flat".

Comment: @mm8 Could you elaborate, perhaps give a brief example? I've edited the post to try and clarify what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When I cut and paste your code, and correct a few issues (Just stuff in $NewADUserParams like = "boss" instead of = boss) so it'll run on my machine, everything is grouped- although it's not as fancy. All the General's are together, etc. I added a column showing the grouping so it's easier to see.

If you comment out 
    $ListViewItemsSource.GroupDescriptions.Add((New-Object System.Windows.Data.PropertyGroupDescription "Grouping"))

you should see the data in order that it was added, instead of grouped together.

```
Function GetListViewItemsSource() {

   Param ($NewADUserParams)

   $Data = @()

   $Groupings = @{
       DEFAULT      = "Other";
       GENERAL      = "General";
       ACCOUNT      = "Account";
       ORGANIZATION = "Organization";
   }

   $IgnoredKeys = @("PassThru", "Enabled")

   $GroupingsMap = @{
       Description           = $Groupings.GENERAL;
       UserPrincipalName     = $Groupings.ACCOUNT;
       DisplayName           = $Groupings.GENERAL;
       SamAccountName        = $Groupings.ACCOUNT;
       AccountExpirationDate = $Groupings.ACCOUNT;
       Name                  = $Groupings.GENERAL;
       Company               = $Groupings.ORGANIZATION;
   }

   ForEach ($Key in $NewADUserParams.Keys) {

       If ($IgnoredKeys -contains $Key) { Continue; }

       $Grouping = $Groupings.DEFAULT

       If ($GroupingsMap.ContainsKey($Key)) {
           $Grouping = $GroupingsMap[$Key]
       }

       $Data += New-Object PSObject -prop @{Property = $Key; Value = $NewADUserParams[$Key]; Grouping = $Grouping; }

   }

   $ListViewItemsSource = [System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView] $Data
   $ListViewItemsSource.GroupDescriptions.Add((New-Object System.Windows.Data.PropertyGroupDescription "Grouping"))


   Return $ListViewItemsSource
}


Function ShowModalWindow() {

   Param ($ListViewItemsSource)

   [XML] $ModalWindowXAML = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\mspow\OneDrive\Documents\ModalWindow.xml

   $NodeReader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $ModalWindowXAML)
   $ModalWindow = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $NodeReader )

   $ListView = $ModalWindow.FindName("DataListView")
   $ListView.ItemsSource = $ListViewItemsSource

   $ConfirmButton = $ModalWindow.FindName("ConfirmButton")
   $CancelButton = $ModalWindow.FindName("CancelButton")

   $Response = @{
       Value = 0
   }

   $ConfirmButton.Add_Click( {
        $Response.Value = 1
        $ModalWindow.Close()
    })

   $CancelButton.Add_Click( {
        $ModalWindow.Close()
    })

   $ModalWindow.ShowDialog()

   Return $Response

}

$NewADUserParams = @{
   # ...
   Description = "bar, foo";
   DisplayName = "bar, foo";
   SamAccountName = "foo.bar";
   AccountExpirationDate = "12/31/9999 00:00:00";
   Name = "foo.bar";
   GivenName = "foo";
   Title = 'boss';
   OtherAttributes = 'System.Collections.Hashtable';
   Surname = "bar";
   ChangePasswordAtLogon = $true;
   # etc...
}
$ListViewItemsSource = GetListViewItemsSource -NewADUserParams $NewADUserParams
$ConfirmUserProps = ShowModalWindow -ListViewItemsSource $ListViewItemsSource
```

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        Title="Confirm User Details" Height="580" Width="360" >

    <Grid Margin="10">
        <ListView Name="DataListView" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="475">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="196" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Grouping}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="110" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Property}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="196" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>

            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Margin="5" TextDecorations="Underline" FontSize="13" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
        </ListView>
        <Button Name="ConfirmButton" Content="OK" Height="39" Width="160" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  />
        <Button Name="CancelButton" Content="Cancel" Margin="0" Width="160" Height="39" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    </Grid>

   </Window>
```

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I'm really looking to get the layout just as in the image I posted in the OP. I know it's possible as I did have it working but I just need to figure out where I'm going wrong in the code of XAML layout.